# how to checkout a moved file in git?

Tags: git

Is there any possible to checkout previous version of a file which has been moved in git?

for example:

```
revison 1:  file.txt(new file)
revison 2:  file.txt(modify)
revison 3:  file.txt(modify)
revison 4:  move file.txt to doc/file.txt
```

now master is at revison 4, and I want to get back the snapshot at revision 2
then I type:

```
cd doc; git checkout HEAD^2 file.txt
```

I got:

```
error: pathspec 'HEAD^2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `doc/file.txt` doesn't exist at that point, and `HEAD^2` means the second parent, not the parent of the parent, so you want something like this:

```
git checkout HEAD~2 -- file.txt
git mv file.txt doc/file.txt
```

Or even easier:

```
git show HEAD~2:file.txt > doc/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HEAD~2`, not `HEAD^2` - it works for me.

Syntax `HEAD^2` is only relevant if HEAD was merge commit, and means to get second parent commit (not common!).

Syntax `HEAD~2` is used to specify parent of parent of current commit.

Comment: You also need to use the path the file had in that rev: after `cd doc`, `file.txt` is `../file.txt` in revs 1-3, so if `HEAD` names rev 4, `HEAD~2:file.txt` is the file in question.  The path relative to `doc` is `../file.txt` (which is where `checkout` will put it).

Answer (score 0):

Try `git checkout HEAD^^^ file.txt` or `git checkout HEAD~2 file.txt`

Also, try and use the branch name when you can. It will help if you ever need to look at the reflog later on.

You can also use `git log` to get the hash of the commit you want. Let's say its 3c142.

Then you can use `git checkout 3c142 file.txt`